# Is there a substitue for <iframe> in HTML5 without using JS or CSS trick?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to create system where anyone can embed a piece of HTML code without using `<iframe>`. Is there anything out there that only uses HTML5?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the user to put arbitrary HTML on your page.

In practice, yes:

#### No JS

- Allowing the user to directly insert HTML to the page
- Allowing the user to provide a url for a predefined `<iframe>` (I assume this is what you meant)

#### JS

- AJAX, assuming that content source is from the same domain
- Cross-domain AJAX, if the server allows [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- Script-loaders + JS template parsers + JS-written templates. Basically everything written in JS since script loaders bypass the [Same-Origin Policy SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

But injecting arbitrary content **WILL have security consequences** so prepare for the worst.